# Can I use AVFoundation to stream downloaded video frames into an OpenGL ES texture?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, streaming, avfoundation

I've been able to use AVFoundation's `AVAssetReader` class to upload video frames into an OpenGL ES texture. It has a [caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242131/using-avassetreader-to-read-stream-from-a-remote-asset), however, in that it fails when used with an `AVURLAsset` that points to remote media. This failure isn't well documented, and I'm wondering if there's any way around the shortcoming.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's some API that was released with iOS 6 that I've been able to use to make the process a breeze. It doesn't use `AVAssetReader` at all, and instead relies on a class called `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput`. An instance of this class can be added to any `AVPlayerItem` instance via a new `-addOutput:` method.

Unlike the `AVAssetReader`, this class will work fine for `AVPlayerItem`s that are backed by a remote `AVURLAsset`, and also has the benefit of allowing for a more sophisticated playback interface that supports non-linear playback via `-copyPixelBufferForItemTime:itemTimeForDisplay:` (instead of of `AVAssetReader`'s severely limiting `-copyNextSampleBuffer` method.

---

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
// Initialize the AVFoundation state
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:someUrl options:nil];
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler:^{

    NSError* error = nil;
    AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];
    if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded)
    {
        NSDictionary* settings = @{ (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] };
        AVPlayerItemVideoOutput* output = [[[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:settings] autorelease];
        AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        [playerItem addOutput:[self playerItemOutput]];
        AVPlayer* player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

        // Assume some instance variable exist here. You'll need them to control the
        // playback of the video (via the AVPlayer), and to copy sample buffers (via the AVPlayerItemVideoOutput).
        [self setPlayer:player];
        [self setPlayerItem:playerItem];
        [self setOutput:output];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ Failed to load the tracks.", self);
    }
}];

// Now at any later point in time, you can get a pixel buffer
// that corresponds to the current AVPlayer state like this:
CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [[self output] copyPixelBufferForItemTime:[[self playerItem] currentTime] itemTimeForDisplay:nil];
```

Once you've got your buffer, you can upload it to OpenGL however you want. I recommend the horribly documented `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` function, because you'll get hardware acceleration on all the newer devices, which is *much* faster than `glTexSubImage2D()`. See Apple's [GLCameraRipple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html) and [RosyWriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110) demos for examples.

Comment: It's not _horribly_ documented, there's some pretty good stuff in the header file.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2023, `CGLTexImageIOSurface2D`  is *much* faster than `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` for getting CVPixelData into an OpenGL texture.

Ensure the CVPixelBuffers are IOSurface backed and in the right format:

```objectivec
videoOutput = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:@{
                (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
                (id)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey: @{},
            }];
            videoOutput.suppressesPlayerRendering = YES;

Glint texture;
glGenTextures(1, & texture);
```

Then to get each frame

```objectivec
pixelBuffer = [output copyPixelBufferForItemTime:currentTime itemTimeForDisplay:NULL];
if (NULL == pixelBuffer) return;

let surface = CVPixelBufferGetIOSurface(pixelBuffer);
if (!surface) return;

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, texture);
CGLError error = CGLTexImageIOSurface2D(CGLGetCurrentContext(),
                                            GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,
                                            GL_RGBA,
                                            (int)IOSurfaceGetWidthOfPlane(surface, 0),
                                            (int)IOSurfaceGetHeightOfPlane(surface, 0),
                                            GL_BGRA,
                                            GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV,
                                            surface,
                                            0);
```

[more info](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/blob/master/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CGLIOSurface.h)