# AVAsset "tracksWithMediaType" returns an empty array

Tags: ios, avasset

These is the beginning o a method I am using to merge videos together

```
-(void) mergeVideosAndAudio:(AVAsset *)audioAsset{

    //Load Video Assets

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *dirFiles;
    if ((dirFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[self documentsDirectory] error:&error]) == nil) {
        // handle the error
    };
    // find all the temp files
    NSArray *movFiles = [dirFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH 'temp'"]];
    NSLog(@"The are %i temp files",movFiles.count);

    //Create assets array
    NSMutableArray *assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < movFiles.count; i++) {
        NSString *videoURL = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp%i.mov", i]];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoURL];

        AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
        [assets addObject:videoAsset];

    }
        NSLog(@"assets:%i ", assets.count);
    // a second way
    for (id obj in assets)
        NSLog(@"obj: %@", obj);

    //Create the composition
    AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

    // 1 - Video track
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                        preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    CMTime videoTrackDuration;
    for (int j = 0; j < assets.count; j++) {
        AVURLAsset *currentAsset = assets[j];
        videoTrackDuration = CMTimeAdd(videoTrackDuration, currentAsset.duration);
        CMTime time;
        if (j == 0) {
            time = kCMTimeZero;

        }else{
            AVURLAsset *previousAsset = assets[j-1];
            time = previousAsset.duration;
        }

        AVAssetTrack *assetTrack = [[currentAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

        [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, currentAsset.duration) ofTrack:assetTrack atTime:time error:nil];
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the `tracksWithMediaType` property of currentAsset is an empty array.
Here is the console

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that currentAsset actually points to a real file on the file system?

Comment: @jlw As I understand it currentAsset takes the file stored in the assets array which can be seen in the console.Right?

Comment: Yes, but my question was if all the currentAssets are playable via AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayer.  It is possible to create an AVAsset with an NSURL pointing to a location that does not actually hold a file.

Comment: If it is playable, note the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326728/playing-video-from-within-app

Comment: Did you get any solution for it ? getting same issue in my code.

Comment: @UserDev Yes I figured out why I was getting this. The aim was to stitch a bunch of tiny videos together but apparently there is minimum number of frames that .mov files must have in order to be playable and recognized as video files (don't remember exactly how many but I'll say about 1 second).  Ended up going a different direction

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242131/using-avassetreader-to-read-stream-from-a-remote-asset)?

I'm working on a solution now that KVO's the tracks key:

```
[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:kTracksKey options:opts context:nil];
```