# AVPlayer fails to play video and AVURLAsset return empty array of tracks

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avurlasset

Before posting my question, I tried with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508823/avasset-trackswithmediatype-returns-an-empty-array).

Currently I am migrating my project from `MPMoviewPlayer` to `AVPlayer`.
In that moment Video file not played if I changed name with French characters. AVURLAsset will return empty tracks array. 
Also, `asset.playable` returns `NO`.

Here is my code :

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilePath];
videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilePath isDirectory:NO];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
if([asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].count == 0) {
    NSLog(@"No Video Track");

} else if([asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].count == 0) {
    NSLog(@"No Audio Track");

}
```

If you observe my File path `Users/Axio-Mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices..../Library/Caches/AppFiles/première journée French_accent File name â ê i-xiufm2.mp4` you can see french accented characters. Is that the impact ?

[image]

Comment: Is that Video file is not supported by iOS ?