# Acessing Video Frames in Real Time iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

I have to access video from a server and I want to be able to acess its frames in real time so that I can do some image processing on them.

I know how to do it offline using the AVAssetReader but this solution does not work for real time processing.

Answer (score 9):

You can access frames of a remote asset in realtime using `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` (with thanks to [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/23-video/core-image-video/)).

p.s. always check your remote asset isn't being blocked by [App Transport Security](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31254725/22147).

p.p.s `AVAssetReader`'s support for remote assets [is complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6409642/22147).

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {        
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "http://0.s3.envato.com/h264-video-previews/80fad324-9db4-11e3-bf3d-0050569255a8/490527.mp4")!)
    let videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: [String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        player.currentItem!.add(videoOutput)
        player.play()

        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(displayLinkDidRefresh(link:)))
        displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.main, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
    }

    func displayLinkDidRefresh(link: CADisplayLink) {
        let itemTime = videoOutput.itemTime(forHostTime: CACurrentMediaTime())

        if videoOutput.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime) {
            if let pixelBuffer = videoOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime, itemTimeForDisplay: nil) {
                print("pixelBuffer \(pixelBuffer)") // yay, pixel buffer
                let image = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer) // or maybe CIImage?
                print("CIImage \(image)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After processing the image, how can you play then on playback ?

Comment: You can draw the `CIImage` into a `GLKView` just as they did in the objc.io article: https://github.com/objcio/core-image-video/blob/master/CoreImageVideo/CoreImageView.swift

Comment: Is it possible to call `displayLinkDidRefresh` manually from the view `draw` function? I got it working with a `CADisplayLink`, but if I call it manually `itemTime` always returns 0, even though `CACurrentMediaTime` advances...